# How to sort an array of string by similarity to specific key

Tags: arrays, swift, string, sorting

Given is the following:

`var theArray: [String] = ["uncool", "chill", "nifty", "precooled", "dandy", "cool"]`

I want to sort the array by **how similar the words are** to the key word.

`var keyWord: String = "cool"`

The wanted result would be:

`print// ["cool", "uncool", "precooled", ...]` and then it does not matter anymore. But the words that `are` the key or `contain it` should be the very first objects.

My closest tryout so far has been:

```
let _theArray = entries.sorted { element1, element2 in

     return element1.contains(keyWord) && !element2.contains(keyWord)
}
```

But that results in `uncool` being the first item, then `precooled` and the most related item `cool` even comes after `nifty` .

What am I missing?

Comment: your sort is in descending for details please check this sorted function link https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array/2905744-sorted

Comment: Your code produces ["uncool", "precooled", "cool", "chill", "nifty", "dandy"], with all strings containing "cool" coming first in the array.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can define your own similarity sorting method. Note that I have also added a hasPrefix priority over the ones which only contains the keyword which you can just remove if you don't want it:

```
var theArray = ["chill", "nifty", "precooled", "cooldaddy", "cool", "coolguy", "dandy", "uncool"]
let key = "cool"

let sorted = theArray.sorted {
    if $0 == key && $1 != key {
        return true
    }
    else if $0.hasPrefix(key) && !$1.hasPrefix(key)  {
        return true
    }
    else if !$0.hasPrefix(key) && $1.hasPrefix(key)  {
        return false
    }
    else if $0.hasPrefix(key) && $1.hasPrefix(key)
        && $0.count < $1.count  {
        return true
    }
    else if $0.contains(key) && !$1.contains(key) {
        return true
    }
    else if !$0.contains(key) && $1.contains(key) {
        return false
    }
    else if $0.contains(key) && $1.contains(key)
        && $0.count < $1.count {
        return true
    }
    return false
}

print(sorted)   // ["cool", "coolguy", "cooldaddy", "uncool", "precooled", "chill", "nifty", "dandy"]
```

You can also extend Sequence and create a sorted by key similarity method:

```
extension Sequence where Element: StringProtocol {
    func sorted<S>(by key: S) -> [Element] where S: StringProtocol {
        sorted {
            if $0 == key && $1 != key {
                return true
            }
            else if $0.hasPrefix(key) && !$1.hasPrefix(key)  {
                return true
            }
            else if !$0.hasPrefix(key) && $1.hasPrefix(key)  {
                return false
            }
            else if $0.hasPrefix(key) && $1.hasPrefix(key)
                && $0.count < $1.count  {
                return true
            }
            else if $0.contains(key) && !$1.contains(key) {
                return true
            }
            else if !$0.contains(key) && $1.contains(key) {
                return false
            }
            else if $0.contains(key) && $1.contains(key)
                && $0.count < $1.count {
                return true
            }
            return false
        }
    }
}
```

---

```
let sorted = theArray.sorted(by: key)  // "cool", "coolguy", "cooldaddy", "uncool", "precooled", "chill", "nifty", "dandy"]
```

---

And the mutating version as well:

```
extension MutableCollection where Element: StringProtocol, Self: RandomAccessCollection {
    mutating func sort<S>(by key: S) where S: StringProtocol {
        sort {
            if $0 == key && $1 != key {
                return true
            }
            else if $0.hasPrefix(key) && !$1.hasPrefix(key)  {
                return true
            }
            else if !$0.hasPrefix(key) && $1.hasPrefix(key)  {
                return false
            }
            else if $0.hasPrefix(key) && $1.hasPrefix(key)
                && $0.count < $1.count  {
                return true
            }
            else if $0.contains(key) && !$1.contains(key) {
                return true
            }
            else if !$0.contains(key) && $1.contains(key) {
                return false
            }
            else if $0.contains(key) && $1.contains(key)
                && $0.count < $1.count {
                return true
            }
            return false
        }
    }
}
```

---

Comment: By using `.localizedCaseInsensitiveContains(key)` eligible with **CaseInsensitive** pattern matching. :)

Comment: @Jack The question is how to do a custom sort. The input provided by the OP it is all lowercase and has no mentions about it. So you don't even know if thats what OP needs.

Comment: @Jack  Case Insensitive (not localized) sample   https://www.dropbox.com/s/bhc5fr3x5q4bvgl/Case%20Insensitive%20Similarity%20Sort.playground.zip?dl=1

Comment: @LeoDabus one more trick  - [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/n9gt3kifw2s23kn/Case%20Insensitive_Jack.swift?dl=0#)

Comment: @Jack  Case Insensitive (Localized) sample https://www.dropbox.com/s/eiml3zpxs45lp9t/Localized%20Case%20Insensitive%20Similarity%20Sort.zip?dl=1

Comment: @LeoDabus Good addition:)

Comment: if the array is ["chill", "nifty", "precooled", "cooldaddy", "cool", "coolguy", "dandy", "uncool"], the result is not correct: ["cool", "uncool", "coolguy", "cooldaddy", "precooled", "chill", "nifty", "dandy"]

Comment: @LeoDabus , can you please check this issue , when we put "uncool" at the end of the array ?

Comment: @HassanTaleb yes there was a missing condition. Check my last edit.

Answer (score 3):

First you need a measure of how similar two strings are. Here's a simple example:

```
extension String {
    func equalityScore(with string: String) -> Double {
        if self == string {
            return 2     // the greatest equality score this method can give
        } else if self.contains(string) {
            return 1 + 1 / Double(self.count - string.count)   // contains our term, so the score will be between 1 and 2, depending on number of letters.
        } else {
            // you could of course have other criteria, like string.contains(self)
            return 1 / Double(abs(self.count - string.count))
        }
    }
}
```

Once you have that, you can use it to sort the array:

```
var theArray: [String] = ["uncool", "chill", "nifty", "precooled", "dandy", "cool"]

var compareString = "cool"

theArray.sort { lhs, rhs in
    return lhs.equalityScore(with: compareString) > rhs.equalityScore(with: compareString)
}
```

Result: `["cool", "uncool", "precooled", "chill", "nifty", "dandy"]`

Comment: if the array is : ["chill", "nifty", "precooled", "cooldaddy", "cool", "coolguy", "dandy", "uncool"] the result is incorrect: ["cool", "uncool", "coolguy", "precooled", "cooldaddy", "chill", "nifty", "dandy"]