# Sort Array by custom rule

Tags: arrays, swift, sorting

I'm looking to sort my array by time but rather than from 0000h to 2359h, I want it to be sorted from 0600h and end at 0559h. The line of code below sorts my array of alarms by their date value (which is of Date type), but obviously from 0000h onwards. Is there a simple way to sort from a certain point or do I need to divide the array into two (one from 6am to midnight, and one from midnight to 5:59am)?

```
array.sort { $0.time.date.compare($1.time.date) == .orderedAscending }
```

Comment: What type are your dates? Or rather the elements of your array?

Comment: What do you mean sort from a certain point? Like only sort elements after a certain index or with a value greater than a particular value?

Comment: Can you elaborate on exactly what you're looking for?

Comment: Your question isn't clear at all. You have `Dates`, not `hours`, that's strange behavior. Show examples and the expected result with different edges cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First extend `Date` to make it easier to extract hour and minute components from it.

```
extension Date {
    var hour: Int { Calendar.current.component(.hour, from: self) }
    var minute: Int { Calendar.current.component(.minute, from: self) }
}
```

Then you can create a custom sort as shown in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47132167/2303865):

```
array.sort {  
    if $0.time.date.hour < 6, $1.time.date.hour >= 6 { return false }
    if $1.time.date.hour < 6, $0.time.date.hour >= 6 { return true  }
    return ($0.time.date.hour, $0.time.date.minute) < ($1.time.date.hour, $1.time.date.minute)
}
```

---

Playground testing:

```
let date1 = DateComponents(calendar: .current, year: 2016, month: 12, day: 10, hour: 23, minute: 0).date!
let date2 = DateComponents(calendar: .current, year: 2017, month: 11, day: 5, hour: 3, minute: 0).date!
let date3 = DateComponents(calendar: .current, year: 2018, month: 8, day: 6, hour: 6, minute: 0).date!
let date4 = DateComponents(calendar: .current, year: 2019, month: 9, day: 27, hour: 7, minute: 0).date!
let date5 = DateComponents(calendar: .current, year: 2020, month: 10, day: 30, hour: 2, minute: 0).date!

var dates = [date1,date2,date3,date4,date5]

dates.sort {
    if $0.hour < 6, $1.hour >= 6 { return false }
    if $1.hour < 6, $0.hour >= 6 { return true  }
    return ($0.hour,$0.minute) < ($1.hour,$1.minute)
}
dates  // "Aug 6, 2018 at 6:00 AM", "Sep 27, 2019 at 7:00 AM", "Dec 10, 2016 at 11:00 PM", "Oct 30, 2020 at 2:00 AM", "Nov 5, 2017 at 3:00 AM"]
```